# Коментарии к фото в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно добавить комментарии к изображениям. Создал таблицу комментарии - id, content_id, user_id, text .
Как запросом добавить запись в бд с комментарием для фото ??
Насколько я понимаю, то нужно в view

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin();
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>
```

Потом значение, которое будет введено в textarea записать в переменную, и вставить в запрос

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->insert('comments', [
                ...
                'text' => $text, //переменная с комментарием
            ])->execute();
```

Если все так нужно делать, то что прописать, чтобы в представлении c изображениями, получить доступ к ActiveForm с данными с комментариями, потому, что ошибка -

> Getting unknown property: frontend\models\Content::text.

Значение text находится в

> frontend\models\Comments

Comment: а просто `$comment->save()` в методе контроллера, который будет срабатывать при отправке комментария вам не подходит?

Comment: просто само текстовое поле, должно быть в представлении, не понимаю каким образом в view фото - получить доступ к ActiveForm другого представления

Comment: также как и в любом другом, выводите нужную модель через `actionView`, посмотрите любой дефолтный метод `actionCreate` в контроллере

Comment: вывел нужную модель, теперь доступ есть, но строке теперь не создание нового сообщения, а сообщение, что уже есть, и оно предлагает апдейт

Comment: нужно в контроллере комментов вывести модель вида изображения?

Comment: связать с фотографиями можно через `relations`, а комментарий вы создаёте через  `new Comment`?

Comment: `$model = new Comments();` в контроллере, если Вы об этом

Answer (score 1):

```
Getting unknown property: frontend\models\Content::text.

frontend\models\Comments
```

Только меня смущает что модели разные?

```
class Content extends ActiveRecord {
    public $_comments;

    public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes) {

            $comment = new Comment();
            $comment->content_id = $this->id;
            $comment->text = $comment;

            if(!$comment->save()){
                //$comment->getErrors();
            }


        parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getComments() {
        return $this->hasOne(Comment::className(), ['content_id' => 'id']);
    }

}
```

В вьюхе

```
$form->field($model, '_comments')->textarea(['rows' => 6])
```

Comment: спасибо, но не работает почему-то , и ошибки нет, просто страница перезагружается после нажатия на кнопку , в бд пусто.

Comment: Вы явно что-то делаете не так. Попробуйте воспользоваться отладкой ну или var_dump'ить.

Модель присваивается в контроллере?
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())

Попробуйте расскоментировать и вывести $comment->getErrors();
А также для Content в том месте где сохраняете